# Using Bayes theorem in practice

Tags: probability

I have a problem with this task. We have 30 boxes. In this 30 can be 0, 1 or 2 bad one. Probability of having 0, 1 or 2 bad boxes is the same (0.3). What's the probability of situation that we have 2 wrong boxes in 30 boxes, provided that all 10 random boxes that we draw from 30 are good.

We know from Bayes rule that

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B|A0)P(A0)+P(B|A1)P(A1)+P(B|A2)P(A2)}
$$

$A(n)$ - situation  when we have n bad boxes in all (30)

$B$ - we draw 10 boxes and all of them are good

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{\binom {30} {10} * 0.3 * 0.3}{\binom {30} {10} * 0.3 * 0.3 + \binom {30} {10} * 0.3 * 0.3 + \binom {30} {10} * 0.3 * 0.3}
$$

I don't know if I'm thinking right.

Comment: $0.3+0.3+0.3 \not = 1$.  Do you mean $\dfrac13$ ?

Comment: Yeah. It is 1/3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If there are no bad boxes, then the probability of drawing ten good boxes is $1$.
- If there is one bad box, then the probability of drawing ten good boxes is $\dfrac{20}{30} =\dfrac23$.
- If there is two bad boxes, then the probability of drawing ten good boxes is $\dfrac{20 \times 19}{30 \times 29}=\dfrac{38}{87}$.

So if the prior probabilities of $0,1,2$ bad boxes are equal, then after observing ten good boxes, the posterior probability of $2$ bad boxes is $$\dfrac{\frac13 \times \frac{38}{87}}{\frac13 \times 1+\frac13 \times \frac{2}{3}+\frac13 \times \frac{38}{87}} = \dfrac{38}{183} \approx 0.20765$$

Comment: Why you didn't use $\binom {30} {10}$ to show random drawing ?

Comment: I also don't understand how do you get this fractal 20/30 and 38/87.

Comment: If you prefer, if there is one bad box then the probability of drawing ten good boxes is $\dfrac{{30-1 \choose 10}}{{30 \choose 10}}$, while if there are two bad boxes then the probability of drawing ten good boxes is $\dfrac{{30-2 \choose 10}}{{30 \choose 10}}$.  They are still $\dfrac{2}{3}$ and  $\dfrac{38}{87}$ when simplified